# Jquery Ajax returning NaN

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, nan

I'm using jQuery ajax, and I'm trying to return the value "5.0000" from the php file and after, convert the value to float.

I'm sure that the value returning from the PHP file is "5.0000" because I used the alert() and document.write(). But when I convert this value using parseFloat(value); and use it inside alert, or document.write, it prints "NaN".

OBS: I just tested it in firefox, and it returned correctly, but in chrome it is still returning "NaN", why!?

Anyone, help me? I used all my day trying to fix this issue... :(

Comment: remove chrome cache and show the full code

Comment: That indeed, solves a lot of problems. I wouldn't know any other explanation, codewise it seems valid.

Comment: @Osa cache should break `alert` and `document.write` as well.

Comment: `parseFloat("5.0000")` returns `5` for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use an INFINITY constant to guard against NaN:

```
 parseFloat(value + Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
```

If the result is `Infinity`, `value` is probably `""`

If the result is `NaN`, `value` is probably `undefined`

Comment: Why not check the `value` directly. That way you would know for sure, not guess?